# I am making a website landing page and the menus div is failing to appear in front of my background. How can I force the div to appear in front?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to place my Menu Div above my background, and it is failing to appear at all. Even in inspect element nothing appears when I try to show where the div is. I have already tried z-index and position relative/absolute/fixed.

I am trying to make a landing page for my website and have been stuck up on this for a long time now. I have tried rearranging the order of the Menu Div in front of the

This is My HTML Code

```css
.body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.menu_top{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100;
  z-index: 5;
}

.home_logo_box{
  z-index: 5;
}

.home_logo{
  top: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 42%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Home
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="coincontrast_home.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"; style="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div src="particles">
        <div id="particles-js"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="particles.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div src="menu_top">
        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/33/33447.png" class="home_logo">
    </div>
    <div class="home_logo_box">
        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/87/87386.png" class="home_logo">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are no error messages

Comment: Please add working snippet since we dont know what you have in style.css and other js files that you used without that we cant. Any how try by giving z-index to div to higher value to visible

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to tell what you are trying to do since we don't have access to the images that you've given relative paths for or the Javascript files that you have added. Can you replicate the issue using CodePen (https://codepen.io/pen/) and public assets for people to play with?

Comment: Please start by getting the script tags outside the body and place them at the top or bottom of your page.

Comment: In your `CSS` you are defining `menu_top` as a class, but in your `HTML` there is no element with this class. I believe you may have used `src="menu_top"` instead of `class="menu_top"`. Same goes for the `src="particles"`. If you change these to classes, do you get the desired outcome?

Comment: I see you have added a snippet now. By "above" do you mean you want `menu_top` at the top of the page, or actually layered on top of your background? You also say that your `menu div` is not appearing at all, is `menu div` actually `menu_top` in your code? If so, it does appear and it appears in your snippet as well. Please can you clarify was the issue is?

Comment: Thank you @JackU!!! I can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: @BenjaminWoodward I will put it as an answer, and you could mark it as correct if it has helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because you are not giving the `div` elements an `id` or `class`.

```
<div src="menu_top">
```

Should actually be:

```
<div class="menu_top">
```

This means that it will also line up with your `CSS`. If you wanted to change the `div` element to an `id` it would look like this:

```
<div id="menu_top">
```

And you need to change your `CSS` from: `.menu_top` to `#menu_top`.

Also, as Thomas Byy said, you should move your `<script>` tags to outside of the `<body>` element, they could be moved to the `<head>` element or just before the closing `</html>` element.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```css
.body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#menu_top{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100;
  z-index: 5;
}

.home_logo_box{
  z-index: 5;
}

.home_logo{
  position: relative;
  bottom:0;
  left: 42%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Home
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="coincontrast_home.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"; style="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div src="particles">
        <div id="particles-js"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="particles.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div id="menu_top">
        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/33/33447.png" class="home_logo">
    </div>
    <div class="home_logo_box">
        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/87/87386.png" class="home_logo">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you shutdown your computer to solve that problem. Hehehe sorry just kidding, I think JackU was right when you name a class you should use a class element so that we you go to your css files you can easily call it. Because in your situation you didn't declare menu_top as a class name, Unfortunately, you make your menu top as a link or source from.